# pandas groupby, counting unique in a group and summing across groups

Tags: pandas

I have a `df` as follows:

```
Date          Stock   Category
2020-01-01    AAA        1
2020-01-01    BBB        2
2020-01-01    CCC        1
2020-01-02    AAA        1
2020-01-02    BBB        2
```

What I am looking to achieve is `sum`  by `Date` and then `cumsum` across `Date` while grouping by `Category`
So the result would look like

```
Date         Category  CUMSUM
2020-01-01       1       2
2020-01-01       2       1
2020-01-02       1       3
2020-01-02       2       2
```

Essentially on `2020-01-01` `2 Stocks` were in `Category 1` and on `2020-01-02 1 Stock` was in `Category 1` resulting in `cumsum=3` on `2020-01-02`.

I have tried `df.groupby(['Date','Category']).agg({'STOCK':'nunique'}).groupby(level=0).cumsum().reset_index()`  but this resulted in each `Category` having the same `CUMSUM` on any given day.
Any ideas on how I can fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much had it, but in your second `groupby` operation you'll want to group on `"Category"` in to calculate a cumulative sum across your dates.

An implicit assumption is that your dates will be sorted after the first groupby operation. So make sure your keep `sort=True` (the default) for your first `groupby` operation. OR ensure your data is sorted by date prior to the groupby opertaion if you want to specify `sort=False` for any reason.

```py
out = (
    df.groupby(["Date", "Category"])
    ["Stock"].nunique()
    .groupby("Category")
    .cumsum() 
)

print(out)
Date        Category
2020-01-01  1           2
            2           1
2020-01-02  1           3
            2           2
Name: Stock, dtype: int64
```